# How get rows with oldest date per year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have task in excel. I think I show you it on example. Let say we have table as:

```
    ID  date
    1   2015-03-11
    1   2015-05-13
    2   2013-01-10
    2   2010-05-11
    1   2014-09-19
    2   2013-04-01
```

I have to make some operations to get rows with oldest date per every year. So I should have:

```
    ID  date
    1   2015-03-11
    1   2014-09-19
    2   2013-01-10
    2   2010-05-11
```

I will grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is but one option.  I like using SQL for this type of work and since Excel can connect to itself as an ODBC data source, that's just what I did here...

1. Create a Named range in excel (I called mine SomeTable)  I do this by selecting the range in question and clicking in the drop down field to the left of the formula space that usually lists the selected cell  (B11 in image below)
2. I then select data, from external sources and select the option for Microsoft Query (ODBC).  Select new data source give it a name (Excel File name) Select microsoft excel driver. click connect. browse to where the file is containing the named range (Some table)  Select ok and then in the 4th option select the named range (SomeTable)... select a place to put the table on a worksheet.
3. Now click in the "table" data it creates and go to the data menu properties. and enter the following in the definition tab under command text

.

```
Select ID, Date 
FROM SomeTable ST 
INNER JOIN 
(Select MIN(date) as mDate, year(date) as mYear
FROM someTable
Group by year(date)) A on 
ST.Date = A.mDate
```

If all done correctly you should get results like this:
[image]

- Column EF is the source table named "SomeTable"
- A10 is where I chose to put the table
- B20 is where the SQL used to get the max per year
  was put.

Comment: It works fine :). Thank you very much, I am really suprised that excel can do that :)

Comment: It's not just excel. It's the ODBC driver that's doing most of the heavy lifting.  But excel is rather feature rich and a highly underutilized tool for analysis purposes.